# Add a column with rowspan to a table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a 2 column by 6 row table which is generated by a framework, so I have no control over how the table is originally built.

I want to add a third column on the right that spans all 6 rows by using jQuery.  The table has an id, but the rows and cells have no defining features.

This is basically the generated table:

```
<table id="tbl1">
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

This is what I want it to be like after jquery has done its magic:

```
<table id="tbl1">
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td rowspan="6">some new data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

I'm using jQuery version 1.7.1

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: So, What you have tried in JQuery..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#tbl1 tr').eq(0).append("<td rowspan='6'>some new data</td>");
```

You can see the jsFiddle of this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/CDUq5/